# How to solidify 3D STL file in Python without a GUI application (e.g: Blender, MeshLab, etc)

Tags: python, 3d

I am trying to solidify/add thickness to a 3D STL file for a research project.

So far, I can do that in Blender, but I don't want to solidify the object in Blender.
[image: check out this image using solidify modifier in Blender]

Are there other ways to solidify/add thickness to the STL file using commands/Python script without GUI application (like Blender, MeshLab, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Parse the STL file using whatever method you like (I've previously posted some Python STL parsing code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54029819/7564109), but you could also use any existing libraries).

Then, identify all boundary edges. Each facet has 3 edges, which you can hash by their indices and count how many times each edge is found in the mesh. Boundary edges will only be found once.

For each triangle, make a copy, flip it, and move its vertices by some amount in the direction of the copied triangle's normal.

If the triangle had any boundary edges, you must generate 2 triangles per boundary edge to connect both the original and copied triangle.